# Jsch to execute a sql query

Tags: java, sql, jsch

I have to remotely access a machine and execute a query, I use ChannelExec and set the commands I have to run. I execute this commands on the machine succesfully:

```
su - postgres
```

and

```
psql -U someUser myDatabase
```

then I'm in the database command line, but when I try to execute a query it always fails, I think because the channel always adds bash: -c and then the command. How can I avoid that in order to execute my query?

Comment: Do you have any code? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24279641/3315914) you have an example of jsch, but I don't know if it solves your problem. Without more information, I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why it failed but here is a work around, instead of:

> ```
> su - postgres
> psql -U someUser myDatabase
> ```

I used

```
psql -U someUser myDatabase -c "query"
```